# Envio de email con if else Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

a la hora de registrarse un cliente pueden haber varias opciones.

1. Traigan datos normales.
2. Traigan un código.
3. Archivo adjuntado.
4. Archivo adjuntado + código

   ```
   public function build()
    {
        if(isset($this->data['codigo'])) {
            $comercial = User::where('tipo_id', 4)->where('codigo', $this->data['codigo'])->first();
            return $this->view('emails.cliente')->with(['comercial' => $comercial]);
        }if(isset($this->data['codigo']) && isset($this->model_name)) {
            $comercial = User::where('tipo_id', 4)->where('codigo', $this->data['codigo'])->first();
            return $this->view('emails.cliente')->with(['comercial' => $comercial])->attach(public_path('/images/modelos/'). $this->model_name);
        }if(isset($this->model_name)) {
            return $this->view('emails.cliente')->attach(public_path('/images/modelos/'). $this->model_name);
        }else{
            return $this->view('emails.cliente');
        }
    }
   ```

Pero el segundo `if` no me funciona, tengo algo mal??? Creo que lo que estoy haciendo es si trae código y nombre de archivo haz ese if.

*Puede ser que al hacer el segundo `if` también seria valido el tercero??

Comment: Nunca entrará al segundo IF dado que el primero cumple antes las condiciones. Le has dicho al primero,  que si trae código, ejecute ese, entonces ese se ejecuta y termina la operación, dado que hay un return al acabar dicho IF.

Comment: Si ya me he dado cuenta, es bastante redundante. Creo que ya lo tengo solucionado

Comment: Te deje una respuesta de todos modos, para que alteres el orden de los IF.

Comment: Supongo que también sera correcta, justo publique una solución por que tenia que comprobarlo de otra forma, puedes verla @Excorpion

Comment: Pruebala, por que el comportamiento deseado se lo darás tu ;)

Comment: Gracias @Excorpion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema, es el orden en que ejecutas los `IF`
Para que el segundo IF pueda ejecutarse, el primero no debe ocurrir. Pero ocurre.
Si quieres que el segundo, tenga prioridad que el primero, deberías colocarlo antes, para que pueda cumplir primero sus condiciones.

```
public function build()
{
  if(isset($this->data['codigo']) && isset($this->model_name)) {
     return [...]
  }
  if(isset($this->data['codigo'])) {
     return [...]
  }
  if(isset($this->model_name)) {
     return [...]     
  }else{
     return $this->view('emails.cliente');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Publico mi solución:

Primero compruebo si viene archivo, si es así compruebo si lleva o no código y depende hace un return u otro, en el caso de que no lleve archivo, compruebo si lleva código y depende hago un return u otro.

```
if(isset($this->model_name)) {
  if(isset($this->data['codigo'])){
     $comercial = User::where('tipo_id', 4)->where('codigo', $this->data['codigo'])->first();
     return $this->view('emails.cliente')->with(['comercial' => $comercial])->attach(public_path('/images/modelos/'). $this->model_name);
  }else{
      return $this->view('emails.cliente')->attach(public_path('/images/modelos/'). $this->model_name);
   }  
 }else{
   if(isset($this->data['codigo'])){
      $comercial = User::where('tipo_id', 4)->where('codigo', $this->data['codigo'])->first();
      return $this->view('emails.cliente')->with(['comercial' => $comercial]);
  }else{
      return $this->view('emails.cliente');
  }
            //return $this->view('emails.cliente');
 }
```